# ErrorException in Filesystem.php - Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to access my Laravel application on my local machine and am receiving the following error when accessing any pages:

> ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 109:
>   file_put_contents(/4d76273a26d1b0fbe2c62bffa1ba6fb5ec8c358b.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied

I have tried running `chmod -R 0777 storage` on my `storage` directory, while this is updated no changes take affect on the Laravel app.

Can someone advise how I can fix this?

Edit:

**Added debug log**

```
#1 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(109): file_put_contents('/4d76273a26d1b0...', '<?php $__env->s...', 0)
#2 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(116): Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem->put('/4d76273a26d1b0...', '<?php $__env->s...')
#3 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(51): Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler->compile('/home/vagrant/l...')
#4 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(147): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/home/vagrant/l...', Array)
#5 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(118): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#6 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(83): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#7 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(53): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#8 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php(199): Illuminate\Http\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#9 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1087): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#10 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Routing\Router->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#11 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /home/vagrant/loot/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php(24): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(96): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#21 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'showLoginForm')
#22 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', 'showLoginForm')
#23 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(140): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(724): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#30 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#35 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#40 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#45 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#49 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#50 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#51 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#52 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#54 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(726): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#55 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(699): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#56 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#57 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#58 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#59 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#60 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/Debugbar.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#61 [internal function]: Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\Debugbar->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#62 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#63 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#64 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#65 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#66 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#67 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#68 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#69 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#70 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#71 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#72 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#73 /home/vagrant/loot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#74 /home/vagrant/loot/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#75 {main}
```

Comment: can you write how exactly you did chmod ?

Comment: who is the owner of storage ? also can you run `php artisan cache:clear `

Comment: Not sure if you've noticed but you appear to be attempting to write your file to the root `/` directory. What **exactly** does your code look like?

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx   8 imran  staff     272  6 Jul 00:26 storage`

Comment: It looks like Laravel is trying to cache the login page view, this is code out of the box so I'm not really sure why it would be trying to store in the root instead of the appropriate folder. Is there anything I can do to debug? (I have included my debug log above)

Comment: weird, laravel should put all compiled views in storage directory, not at the root. is this project open? tried to reinstall the dependencies (clear the vendor directory and rerun `composer update`)?  also, make sure the user who ran the Apache.. it might run under different creds depend on how you install/start it..

Comment: or you could check in `config/filesystem.php` and `.env` file for the path of storage..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I resolved the issue:

The problem was because the following directories were missing: 

- `storage/framework/cache`

- `storage/framework/views`

creating these and setting appropriate permissions resolved the issue

Answer (score 6):

I am running my app in the cloud, however I was experiencing the same issues.

For me, I did not set the right permissions, following solved my problem:
`sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache`
and
`sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`
Credit: [Article by Mateusz Papiernik](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 3):

It was a permission issue for me. I used:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/dmain.com/html/subdirectory

sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/dmain.com/html/subdirectory/bootstrap/cache
```